# Different view hierarchies when using pop-up library

Tags: ios, swift, popup

I'm trying to make a popup appear when clicking a button on a TableView, using the [SCLAlertView-Swift](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift) library.

I'm also attempting to define constraints so that the dimensions are right when the device is rotated. However, it gives me the following error:

> 'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading"> because they have no common
>   ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in
>   different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

I'm suppose I'm trying to get the view from the TableViewController, since I invoke this code from that class.

```
let alert = SCLAlertView()

alert.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

let margins = view.layoutMarginsGuide
alert.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
alert.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
alert.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive=true
alert.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive=true

alert.showInfo("Login", subTitle: "")
```

Why does it say I reference items in different view hierarchies? What can I do to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried hooking it to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` view instead of the `TableViewController` view?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation of `SCLAlertView` [here](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift/blob/master/SCLAlertView/SCLAlertView.swift#L633), it seems it is added as a subView of `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow` .

I would recommend to hook the constraints on the appliction's `UIWindow`, instead of the `TableViewController` 's view.

```
let rv = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow! as UIWindow
let margins = rv.layoutMarginsGuide
```